# Keyboard configuration for shatter?

Tags: shatter

I just picked up Shatter for PC as part of Humble Indie Bundle 6.  Some tips on the [Steam Forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1199474) suggest that there's a way to change the default key bindings, but the configuration pane in the settings program for the Stand-alone version doesn't seem to exist.

**Edit:** Snooping around in the config file doesn't provide much in the way of clues.  The closest hint, in `%localappdata%\Sidhe\SH\data\profiles\default_plr_profile.xml`

```
<SIFPlayerProfile>
    <!-- snip -->
    <profile_data>
        <!-- snip -->
        <Controller_Config>1</Controller_Config>
        <singleplayer_controller_guid>mousekb</singleplayer_controller_guid>
        <player_two_controller_guid>mousekb</player_two_controller_guid>
    </profile_data>
</SIFPlayerProfile>
```

Is there a way I can configure the keybindings for the PC version of Shatter?

Comment: You need to launch the settings editor as administrator. The Steam version does this automatically, but not the standalone version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit the controller mapping you need to use the ShatterSettingsEditor. In the Steam version of the game, choose the 'edit settings' option when launching the game. In the standalone version, find ShatterSettingsEditor, either in the Start menu or under Program Files, and **launch it as administrator**. You'll find the Control Mapping tab appear under the Controller tab, like so:

[image]